# Estimating Speed of Vehicle using Centroid Method two images MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I want to calculate the speed of a vehicle. I got two images that I have to use to calculate the speed. My code up to now is this:

```
% Takes start and end image as it's parameters, compares these to work out
% how fast the vehicle is travelling.
% - Returns 1, if > 30mph.
% - Returns 0, if < 30mph
function result = CheckSpeeding(start_image, end_image)

% Gather the image dimensions
[img_height, img_width] = size(start_image);
img_center_x = img_width / 2;
img_center_y = img_height / 2;

% Split image into regions
% Label regions - pass in img, and the number of connected objects returns 
% matrix where L is an image containing the labels, and num is the number
% of regions
start_image_label = bwlabel(start_image, 4);
end_image_label = bwlabel(end_image, 4);

% Gather stats about the image to use a bit later on in the function
starting_statistics = regionprops(start_image_label, 'ConvexArea',     'BoundingBox');
ending_statistics = regionprops(end_image_label, 'ConvexArea', 'BoundingBox');

% Find the largest object in the picture
% then use this as the bounding box
[start_max_area, start_max_index] = max([starting_statistics.ConvexArea]); %     start_max_area is not required
[end_max_area, end_max_index] = max([ending_statistics.ConvexArea]); % end_max_area is not required
 start_bounding_box = starting_statistics(start_max_index).BoundingBox;
 end_bounding_box = ending_statistics(end_max_index).BoundingBox;

 % Gather the properties of the bounding box
 % then find the centre of the bounding box
 start_bounding_box_pos_x = start_bounding_box(1);
 start_bounding_box_pos_y = start_bounding_box(2);
 start_bounding_box_width = start_bounding_box(3);
 start_bounding_box_height = start_bounding_box(4);
 end_bounding_box_pos_x = end_bounding_box(1);
 end_bounding_box_pos_y = end_bounding_box(2);
 end_bounding_box_width = end_bounding_box(3);
 end_bounding_box_height = end_bounding_box(4);

 start_centroid_x = start_bounding_box_pos_x + (start_bounding_box_width / 2);
 start_centroid_y = start_bounding_box_pos_y + (start_bounding_box_height / 2);
 end_centroid_x = end_bounding_box_pos_x + (end_bounding_box_width / 2);
 end_centroid_y = end_bounding_box_pos_y + (end_bounding_box_width / 2);

 % Calculate the difference (in pixels) between the centre of the image and
 % the centre of the bounding box
 start_diff_px = img_center_y - start_centroid_y;
 end_diff_px = img_center_y - end_centroid_y;

 % Convert the difference in pixels to difference in degrees and add to
 % degrees from vertical (60)
 start_diff_deg = 60 + (start_diff_px * 0.042);
 end_diff_deg = 60 + (end_diff_px * 0.042);

  % Calculate the (horizontal) distance between the camera and the object
  start_distance = 7 * tand(start_diff_deg);
   end_distance = 7 * tand(end_diff_deg);


   % Compare the first and last image to calculate the distance travelled
   % As stated in the requirements, the camera takes pictures of the lane at
   % 0.1s intervals.
   % We then then convert the speed to mph
   distance_travelled = end_distance - start_distance;
   speed_meters = distance_travelled / 0.9  ;
   speed_miles = speed_meters * 2.236;
   disp(speed_miles);



   % We then check to see if the speed exceeds the speed limit, if yes     return
   % 1, if no, return 0.
   if(speed_miles > 30)
     result = 1;
    else
   result = 0;
    end
```

The images I use are those two:

[image: 001.jpg]
[image: 010.jpg]

I call this function from here:

```
 % Takes a comma separated string of the image file names to test
 function TestImages (image_set)

     % Split the string up so that we have the first and the last file.
% this is all that we need for our processing.
% unfortunately, in matlab to work out the array length it is quite
% cumbersome. see '[image_set_c, image_set_r] = size(image_set);'
% this stores the value as a 'cell' so we then need to evaluate this as
% a string 'end_image_name{1}'
image_set = strsplit(image_set,',');
[image_set_c, image_set_r] = size(image_set);
if(image_set_r == 2)
    end_image_name = image_set(image_set_r);
    end_image_name = end_image_name{1};
    end_vehicle = imread(end_image_name);
end
start_image_name = image_set(1);
start_image_name = start_image_name{1};
start_vehicle = imread(start_image_name);

%run the script to check if the vehicle is a fire engine
fire_engine = CheckFireEngine(start_vehicle);

% If a fire engine is found then the authorities ignore it.
% A message is given to inform them.
if (fire_engine > 0)
    display('Alert: Fire engine entering tunnel')
else

    % Segment images, using img subtraction ready for size and speed testing
    % note - size segmented images do not include subtraction
    if(image_set_c == 2)
        start_vehicle_speed_bw = segment_image(start_vehicle, end_vehicle);
        end_vehicle_speed_bw = segment_image(end_vehicle, start_vehicle);
    end
    start_vehicle_width_bw = segment_image(start_vehicle, '');

    % Check that the size is within the boundaries
    oversize =  CheckOverSize(start_vehicle_width_bw);

    % Make sure the same image file hasn't been referenced twice
    image_file_similarity = strcmp(start_image_name,start_image_name);
    if(image_file_similarity ~= 1)
        % Test for speed
        speeding = CheckSpeeding(start_vehicle_speed_bw, end_vehicle_speed_bw);
    else
        speeding = 0;
        display('Alert: Non-moving vehicle found')
    end

    if (oversize > 0)
        display('Alert: Vehicle exceeds size maxium size for tunnel.')
    end

    if (speeding > 0)
        display('Alert: Vehicle speed exceeds 30mph.')
    end

end
```

When I call this function the speed is displayed as zero all the time.

Comment: This line `end_centroid_y = end_bounding_box_pos_y + (end_bounding_box_width / 2);` shouldn´t be `end_centroid_y = end_bounding_box_pos_y + (end_bounding_box_width / 2);` ? Also, can you show us the values of `start_diff_px` and `end_diff_px`  to help solving the problem?
`

Comment: I don't know the values of these two variables as matlab won't allow me to display them.By the way the first image is called 001.jpg and the second 010.jpg.Please let me know if u need more info as I need to fix this issue asap.Thanks